# How to avoid lambda in Python

Tags: python, lambda, pickle

```
def parameterSchaetzung(kontextfreq,a,p,f1):
    parameter = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
    for (s,w) in kontextfreq:
        parameter[s][w] = (kontextfreq[(s,w)] + a[s] * p[w]) / (f1[s] + a[s])
        #print((kontextfreq[(s,w)] + a[s] * p[w]) / (f1[s] + a[s]))
    return parameter
```

I have an error, when I try to write the result of the function in pickle. I think, the problem is because of lambda. How I can solve it?

```
>>> parameter = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
>>> pickle.dump(parameter,open("foo","wb"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 301, in runcode
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x00000000032DA620>: attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed
```

Comment: _What_ error...

Comment: You need to reproduce your indentation accurately when posting Python code. Otherwise you are introducing new problems into the code that you are asking people to read.

Comment: Also please provide enough code so that we can try your code out for ourselves ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Maybe a sample call of the method and the pickle call in this case?

Comment: @wonderb0lt: I have edited the last bit, very easy to reproduce, no need for the function above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lambda` characteristic in known from your program, and you cannot pickle a function.

What you really want is to pickle the data, so just convert to `dict` when dumping:

```
pickle.dump(dict(parameter),f)
```

and convert back when loading

```
parameter = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
parameter.update(pickle.load(f))
```